# Position view objects of one layout with the view objects of other layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: image here for better understanding]I have 3 linear Layouts with three objects each.What i want is to position (lets suppose) image view of third Linear layout with respect to the text view of first Linear layout.
IF the question seems silly,i apologies Being Naive to Android programming.

XML code here abot :

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/uppermainLinear">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orderlistordernumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Order"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-B"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_device_32"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
            android:layout_below="@+id/uppermainLinear">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_device_70"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/ordelistbookingleftImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/tofrom" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.2"
                android:id="@+id/leftLinear"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:id="@+id/orderleftSide">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                        android:id="@+id/ordelistfromLayout">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ordelistfromName"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-B"
                            android:text="mazz khan"
                            android:gravity="bottom"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ordelistfromNameDetail"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:textColor="@color/hint_text_color_two"
                            android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-B"
                            android:text="180-A new Muslim town Lahore"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/ordelistfromName" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ordelisttoName"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-B"
                            android:text="mazz khan"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ordelisttoNameDetail"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
                            android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-B"
                            android:textColor="@color/hint_text_color_two"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:text="180-A new Muslim town Lahore" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:id="@+id/rightLinear"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date_textview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Date"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-R"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/amounttext"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-R"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:text="Amount" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/Deliverytext"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-R"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:text="Delivery Fee" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                android:id="@+id/rightlinearForTrackingOrder"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ordelistDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:textColor="@color/summery_qar_text_color_black"
                    android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-L"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="03-02-2017"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ordelistamountvalue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:textColor="@color/summery_qar_text_color_black"
                    android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-L"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:text="300 QR"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ordelistdeliveryValue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="Ubuntu-L"
                    android:text="20 QR"
                    android:textColor="@color/summery_qar_text_color_black"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ordelistRightOptionImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/edit" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/main_screen_line_divider"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinear"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:id="@+id/orderListRowBottomLine"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </View>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

<-these comment are useless to provide standard code description text->

Comment: Can you draw a picture which illustrates what you want the layout to look like?

Comment: Hard to know what you are trying to do without more details or a picture that ilustrates what you wantto achieve. However, seems like [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) can help you with that.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   i have updated the question..

Comment: @lalongooo i've updated may post.

Comment: To start, the right-most LinearLayout should have `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.